# How to calculate two populations combined mean and standard deviation.

Tags: standard-deviation, means

I'm trying to solve following type of combined date given question. Imagined that there's two factories. They are X and Y. "X" factory has 10 workers and "Y" has 20 workers. These two factory's production respectively given as Σx^2=2950 and ΣY^2=5000. Moreover, "X" factory mean is 18 and "Y" factory mean is 15.

If the whole population is considered as a one. How to calculate the mean and standard deviation in a situation like this one? I'm not expecting the final answer, I rather would like to know the procedure that how to solve such a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\bar{x}=18$ and so $\Sigma x=18\times 10=180$

Similarly, $\bar{y}=15$ so $\Sigma y=15\times20=300$

So the pooled mean is $$\frac{180+300}{10+20}=16$$

For the standard deviation, the combined sum of squares is $2950+5000=7950$

Using the standard formula, the pooled standard deviation is $$\sqrt{\frac{7950}{30}-16^2}=3$$

Comment: Thank you so much your descriptive answer.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @DavidQuinn Would you please help me out with combined correlation.

Comment: @AhmadTalafha is there a particular question you have in mind?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thank you! Yes, I do have something in mind. Let assume that we have $94$ female with two variables height and weight. Let assume that the mean and the standard deviation for the height are (161 cm) and (7), respectively. Similarly, the mean and the standard deviation for the weight are (72 kg) and (23), respectively.

Comment: @DavidQuinn On the other hand, we have $101$ male with two variables also height and weight. Let assume that the mean and the standard deviation for the height are (173 cm) and (8), respectively. Similarly, the mean and the standard deviation for the weight are (80 kg) and (20), respectively. The correlation in the female, $r(height, weight)= 0.49449$. The correlation in the male, $r(height, weight)= 0.56507$. Now, my question is, what is the combined correlation for whole the population ( in height and the weight).

Comment: @AhmadTalafha perhaps you should ask this as a question (although you are expected to show what you have tried) rather than as a comment to another question.

Comment: @DavidQuinn I do not really need an answer. I need a hint, so I would know where to look. Thank you !!

Comment: @AhmadTalafha you just have to use the formulas for mean, standard deviation and correlation to extract the summary statistics like $\Sigma x,\Sigma x^2$ etc...